# how do I replace one line break with two line breaks?

Tags: php, markdown

My markdown eats the enterers from the text that is loaded from another site. Therefore, I would like to write a replacement for one enter for two for it.

I tried to do this:

```php
$description = preg_replace('& #010;', '&# 010;&# 010;', $description);
```

But in the end, only `"No ending delimiter '&' found"` came out.

Comment: You need to put the pattern in delimiters.

Comment: PHP thinks you're trying to use `&` as a delimiter, hence why it tells you you're missing the end. `<singlequote><delimiter><regex><delimiter><globals><singlequote>` is the general form.

Comment: wouldnt you just want `str_replace("\n","\n\n", $input);` ?